# rest.client stuck on waiting

Tags: express, rest-client

The handler for `/` request is

```
module.exports = {  
  homepageHandler: async function (req, res) {
    console.log(`index page.`);
    return JSON.stringify({
      "message": "welcome"
    });
  }
}
```

It is called from `app.js` - `app.get('/', indexControllerModule.homepageHandler);`

I am trying to test this endpoint using `Rest Client` extension.

```
Name: REST Client
Id: humao.rest-client
Description: REST Client for Visual Studio Code
Version: 0.25.1
Publisher: Huachao Mao
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client
```

The request is

```
GET http://localhost:4000/
Content-Type: application/json
```

When I click on `send request, the client seem to be stuck in` waiting` state (see lower left corner) of the pic.

Seem the request is received (output of `` console.log(`index page.`) ``) from `index` handler but the response isn't received. Why?

I tried using `Promise.resolve` for return value but that didn't solve the issue.

```
return Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify({
      "message": "welcome"
    }));
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

silly me! I didn't return any response from the handler

added `res.status(200).send(body)`